# Using a style variable on the Plot

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking to simply allow a variable replacement on the plot, but I keep getting an error.

```
cr20_50up = cross(d1,d9) and d1 > d9
cr20style = cr20_50up ? 1 : 2
plot(d1, title='%K SMA20', color=cr20_50_color, transp=0,style=cr20style)
```

But it doesn't work.

```
line 54: Cannot call `plot` with arguments (series, title=literal string, color=series[color], transp=literal integer, style=series[integer]); available overloads: plot(series, const string, series[color], integer, integer, bool, integer, float, series[integer], bool, series, const bool, const integer, string) => plot; plot(fun_arg__<arg_series_type>, const string, fun_arg__<arg_color_type>, integer, integer, bool, integer, float, series[integer], bool, series, const bool, const integer, string) => plot
```

Any ides?
Thanks
Scott

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking to simply allow a variable replacement on the plot, but I keep getting an error.

The [cannot call with arguments error](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/cannot-call-arguments/) that you keep getting with that code happens because one of `plot()`'s arguments is not in the accepted format.

If we look at [the `plot()` function](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_plot), we see it takes the following values, each with their own type:

- `series` (series)
- `title` (const string)
- `color` (color)
- `linewidth` (integer)
- `style` (integer)
- `transp` (integer)
- `trackprice` (bool)
- `histbase` (float)
- `offset` (integer)
- `join` (bool)
- `editable` (const bool)
- `show_last` (const integer)

Now here's how your code calls `plot()`:

```
cr20style = cr20_50up ? 1 : 2
plot(d1, title='%K SMA20', color=cr20_50_color, transp=0,style=cr20style)
```

The problem is that here we set the `style` argument not to an integer, but to a series. That's because `cr20style` is set conditionally to either `1` or `2`. And while it's true that it's a series of integers, a series is still different from a regular integer in TradingView Pine.

This also unfortunately means the following: you can't set the style of the `plot()` function conditionally.

Probably the best workaround for your code is to create two plots, each with their own style. And then to disable plotting based on `cr20style`. For instance:

```
plot(cr20style == 1 ? d1 : na, title='%K SMA20', 
     color=cr20_50_color, transp=0,style=1)
plot(cr20style == 2 ? d1 : na, title='%K SMA20', 
     color=cr20_50_color, transp=0,style=2)
```